# Initializing a value only on the first call to a recursive function

Tags: c, image, function, recursion, constants

my assignment is to create a function that will color all direct and indirect neighbours with the same color as a given pixel (x, y). Basically It’s supposed to work like a filling tool in Paint.
Thats my code so far:

```
void fill(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t newGrayValue) {
    int grayValue = image->data[y * image->width + x];

    if (image->data[y * image->width + x] == grayValue) {
        image->data[y * image->width + x] = newGrayValue;


        fill(image, x + -1, y + -1, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x +  0, y + -1, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x +  1, y + -1, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x + -1, y +  0, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x +  1, y +  0, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x + -1, y +  1, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x +  0, y +  1, newGrayValue);
        fill(image, x +  1, y +  1, newGrayValue);
    }
}
```

The problem is that with every function call, it’ll reset the variable `greyValue`. Is there a posibility to define `greyValue` based on the input pixel (x, y) *just on the first function call*?

edit: Problem is solved, this is my final code:

```
void fillRecursive(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t grayValue, uint8_t newGrayValue) {
    if (image->data[y * image->width + x] == grayValue) {
        image->data[y * image->width + x] = newGrayValue;


        fillRecursive(image, x + -1, y + -1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x +  0, y + -1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x +  1, y + -1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x + -1, y +  0, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x +  1, y +  0, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x + -1, y +  1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x +  0, y +  1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        fillRecursive(image, x +  1, y +  1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
    }
}

void fill(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t newGrayValue) {
    int grayValue = image->data[y * image->width + x];
    printf("%d\n", grayValue);
    if (grayValue != newGrayValue) {
        fillRecursive(image, x, y, grayValue, newGrayValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `grayValue` a parameter of the recursive function, so that you 
can pass it on to the next calls:

```
void recursive_fill(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t grayValue, uint8_t newGrayValue)
{
    if (image->data[y * image->width + x] == grayValue) {
        image->data[y * image->width + x] = newGrayValue;
        recursive_fill(image, x + -1, y + -1, grayValue, newGrayValue);
        // ...
    }
}
```

and start the recursion with

```
void fill(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t newGrayValue)
{
    recursive_fill(image, x, y, image->data[y * image->width + x], newGrayValue);
}
```

Comment: According to the assignment, the function call has to be `void fill(struct Image *image, int x, int y, uint8_t newGrayValue)`. So that won't work.

Comment: @user3000387: Please look at the edited answer, the fill function looks exactly like that, but makes use of a recursive helper function with an additional parameter. - Note that if you really assign the grayValue only on the first function call (using a static variable) then you could never do a second fill later.

Comment: Thank you. Creating a helper function was really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Make it static:

```
static int grayValue = 0;
if(grayValue == 0)
grayValue=image->data[y * image->width + x];
```

Comment: Now my output image looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/35B2TD8.png). When I'm just checking for `0`instead of `greyValue` it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/VfDdPoz.png).